# How to name UIImage drawn from UIBezierPath() programmatically in Xcode-Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage

How do we name an image programmatically. For example, assign a name to the image generated below. A name that we can use to distinguish the image from other images drawn programmatically.

```
 func drawOval (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, name: String) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
        
        let image = renderer.image { ctx in
            
            let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
            path.stroke()
        }

        // TO DO: Assign this image a name, for example "image01"

        return image
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context of the surrounding code? Is this block you currently have pasted a function?

Comment: Yes, the block pasted is typical function that generates the images dynamically. We need to name the images, so that we can identify them, re-use and insert in cache memory; image = UIImage(named: "...") .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) on each `UIImageView`.  I’m not aware of a way to add an identifier to a `UIImage` directly since it is a subclass of `NSObject` and not `UIView`.  In order to add a tag to an object in Swift, the object must be a view of some kind.

To implement this, you would keep a variable outside of that function that keeps track of the current tag, then increment it in your function.  For example:

```
var currentTag = 0

//Function now returns a UIImageView
func drawOval (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, name: String) -> UIImageView {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        path.stroke()
    }

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.tag = currentTag
    currentTag += 1

    return imageView
}
```

Then later in your code:

```
if (imageView.tag == 0) {
    //Do something
}

//You can also use

let taggedImageView = viewWithTag(0)
```

EDIT: If you want to save the images and load them via one of the available `UIImage` initializers, you can write them to a cache folder on disk, then retrieve them using `UIImage(pathToFile:)`:

```
//This will store the images in the caches directory for your app, which
//the system can clear when the device is low on storage.  It will not be
//cleared while your app is open, though.

func saveImageToCacheDynamically(image: UIImage, name: String) {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let localPath = paths[0].appendingPathComponent(“ImageCache”, isDirectory: true)
    do {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath.absoluteString) {
            //Write the png data representation of the image to disk in plaintext format
            try image.pngData().write(to: localPath.appendingPathComponent("\(name).txt"))
  } else {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: localPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    //Write the png data representation of the image to disk in plaintext format
    try image.pngData().write(to: localPath.appendingPathComponent("\(name).txt"))
  }
} catch {
  print("Error locally saving image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

//Later in your code...
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let localPath = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("ImageCache/\(imageIdentifier).txt")
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath.absoluteString) {
    var fileData: Data!
    do {
        try fileData = Data(contentsOf: localPath)
    } catch {
        print("Error reading image file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    let image = UIImage(data: fileData)
    //Do something with image
} else {
    print("Error: image does not exist")
}
```

Comment: We are trying to name the dynamically generated images, so that we can retrieve them when necessary using;  image = UIImage(named: "...") and use cached memory, when necessary.

Comment: UIImage(named: “”) is generally for images saved in your app bundle, which I don’t believe you can modify once your app is compiled.  You could save the images to a folder on disk, and then load them using UIImage(contentsOfFile: “path/to/file.png”).  I’ll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @adept_cnm see my updated answer.  The UIImage(pathToFile:) initializer will load the image into memory from disk.  I don’t believe there is a way to use UIImage(named:) with images generated at runtime because that initializer looks in your app’s asset catalogs, which cannot be modified outside of Xcode.

Comment: @adept_cnm I have edited my answer with the code I am talking about at the bottom of the answer.  If you have already tried that code, what didn't work about it? What error did you receive?

Comment: Thank you. Please provide example. It could not work. We wrapped the proposal you sent in a; func saveImageToCacheDynamically (image: UIImage, name: String) {...proposal you sent...} and called it from the function generating image dynamically. It could not work. There were errors. Please refer to code we sent earlier with the question, where we inserted the call to proposed method ; // TO DO: Assign this image a name, for example "image01". 
        saveImageToCacheDynamically (image: image!, name: "SomeImageIdentifier.png")

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. We have tried to run the example code you provided. The output: “Error: image does not exist”.
We confirmed an image was generated dynamically from code and received by the proposed example method. 
There could be other problems elsewhere, we appreciate your input. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is something like NSCache...

You can define a cache by something similar to this:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<String, UIImage>()
```

Then you can add objects to the cache like this, where someKeyString is the 'name' you are referring to:

```
imageCache.setObject(someImage, forKey: someKeyString)
```

And then finally you can retrieve images from the cache like

```
imageCache.object(forKey: someKeyString)
```

I would recommend using extensions or something similar to maintain a reference to your cache everywhere in your app.

** NOTE:

NSCaches are cleared when memory space is short, your app closes, etc. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCache)

For more permanent storage, I would recommend using UserDefaults, which Apple describes as "An interface to the user’s defaults database, where you store key-value pairs persistently across launches of your app." Use this for things like profile images or things that won't change very often. I would also recommend looking into Core Data